# LINQ KeyValuePair List select value

Tags: c#, list, linq, key-value

I am sure it has been answered somewhere before but for the love of god I cant find it.

I want to get **a specific Value for a Key** from a KeyValuePair List per LINQ one-liner.

My List:  `List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> LeagueKVPList`

---

I think it goes something like this:

`int x = LeagueKVPList.Where(v => v.Key.(int y)).Value`

But that obviously does not work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: FYI instead of using `KeyValuePair` you could create a list of tuples `List<Tuple<int, int>>` or better yet value tuples that you can name `List<(int First, int Second)>`

Comment: Note the syntactic sugar for tuples in C# actually uses `ValueTuple` not `Tuple`. ValueTuple is a value type, Tuple is a reference type.

Comment: @juharr & JamesFaix thank you both for your informative comments!

Comment: juharr & @JamesFaix thank you both for your informative comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Select` for that

```cs
var values = LeagueKVPList.Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

It returns you all values.

To get a single value you can use `FirstOrDefault`

```cs
var x = LeagueKVPList.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == y).Value;
```

Comment: Note, `FirstOrDefault` will return `default(KeyValuePair<int, int>)` if a match is not found. Both `KeyValuePair` and `int` are value types, so you could get a false `0` result from this.